# Cannot update entity in Entity Framework 4 using POCO

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I have 2 tables : Item and Location (one - many ).

I select one location and I try to update it

The entity goes from `{Id=2, Name="name1",City="city1",Items=null}` to `{Id=2, Name="name1", City="city2",Items=null}` and i want to save the updates.
The update method from the base class is:

```
        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            Entities.Attach(entity);
            Context.ObjectStateManager
                   .ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        }
```

I make several updates just like this on other tables with no problems but in this case I get `"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."` and I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try specifying: `MergeOptions.NoTracking` for the context and see if that solves your problem.

Also, you can try `Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out stateEntry)` to see if the object is there and can be updated.

Comment: stateEntry=null, it seems the object is not there and it shouldn't be, i just can't figure out why i cannot attach it

Comment: MergeOption.NoTracking did the job. In which situations must that be set when using POCO?

Comment: MSDN describes the relationship between NoTracking and POCO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx although its very terse on the subject.